# How to call model function in query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[Function From Customer to Order & Function check active order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbjww.png)

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPCp.png) 
How to get customers where doesnt have relation in Order Models and customers where have relation in Order but the Order was inactive ??

Get Customer where doesnt have relation in order and customer where have relation in Order but Order state was inactive/expired

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: We don't debug images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Customer::with('orders')->whereDoesntHave('orders')->orWhereHas('orders', function($query){
        $query->select('orders.state')
            ->from('orders')
            ->whereColumn('orders.customer_id', 'customers.id');
    }, 'expired')->get();
```